# Unable to start jira - Unable to execute mojo exception

Tags: maven, maven-3, jira, pom.xml

I am running JIRA 7.0.2 in my system  and Atlassian SDK 6.1.2.

OS-Windows 7

I have my own plugins and when  ever I try to run jira by atlas-debug I get this exception.

```
--- maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:generate-manifest (default-generate-manifest) @ jira-menu-items ---
Generating a manifest for this plugin
using maven-bundle-plugin v2.5.3
Manifest com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial:jira-menu-items:atlassian-plugin:1.1 : The default package '.' is not permitted by the Import-Package syntax. 
 This can be caused by compile errors in Eclipse because Eclipse creates 
valid class files regardless of compile errors.
The following package(s) import from the default package null
Error(s) found in manifest configuration
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2:32.854s
Finished at: Tue Nov 24 22:24:04 IST 2015
Final Memory: 66M/682M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:generate-manifest (default-generate-manifest) on project jira-menu-items: Unable to execute mojo: Error(s) found in manifest configuration -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-menu-items</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Milind Company</name>
        <url>http://www.milind.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>jira-menu-items</name>
    <description>This is the com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial:jira-menu-items plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.18</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
               <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <Export-Package>net.gisnas.jira.mailqueue.api,</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                                </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.0.2</jira.version>
        <amps.version>6.1.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.6</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This key is used to keep the consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the key to generate bundle. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Settings.xml

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>C:\Users\Milind\.m2\repository</localRepository>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>atlassian-repositories</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
                    <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
                    <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>atlassian-contrib</id>
                    <name>Atlassian Contrib Repository</name>
                    <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
                    <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
                    <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>atlassian-repositories</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: It seems like a compile error - did you try to compile in Eclipse?

Comment: @Robert Yess It's compile Error. i tried with netbeans and CMD it giving me same error. but why i don't understand. i try with clean and build also . but giving me same error.

Comment: Try to check compile errors directly in Eclipse, this error you're receiving in command line is secondary

Comment: @Robert Getting same error :(

Comment: @Robert : I am not get Solution but ya i am able to start jira after remove `<configuartion>` tag from pom.xml. but with that all plugin is failed to start and jira lock. so do you know solution now ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to clean up the target directory within your plugin directory or simply use  command `atlas-clean` from plugin directory and run your plugin.
2. If you've made some changes in pom.xml then before running plugin, you should execute this command first `atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Every time you made changes in pom you should execute this command.
3. Please, check once that your JDK version is 8 because JIRA 7.x will only works with JDK 8.
4. You've set incompatible version for amps in dependency. Use 6.1.2 instead of 5.x

   com.atlassian.maven.plugins
               maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin
               5.0.18

And if you are trying to debug the code in Eclipse after running JIRA from command then you should specify the port number to attach debugger. Your command will be like this `atlas-debug --jvm -debug -port 5005`.

Hope this will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I am not get Solution but ya i am able to start jira after remove `<configuartion>` tag from pom.xml. but with that all plugin is failed to start and jira lock. so do you know solution now ?